# missing FROM-clause entry for table in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

This is my query builder method:

```
def query_builder(search_parameter):
    query = BusinessOwner.query
    # query = query.select_from(BusinessOwnerTask)
    query = query.join(services, BusinessOwnerTask.services_id == services.c.id). \
        join(BusinessOwnerTask, BusinessOwnerTask.business_owner_id == BusinessOwner.id)
    query = query.filter(services.c.service_grade_id == search_parameter.service_grade)
    if len(search_parameter.name) > 0:
        query = query.filter(BusinessOwner.name == search_parameter.name)
    if len(search_parameter.service_types) > 0:
        query = query.filter(BusinessOwnerTask.services_id.in_(search_parameter.service_types))

    return query
```

This code has been run on **sqlite3** ,However, when **query.all()** calls, it complains on **postgres**:

> ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) missing FROM-clause
>   entry for table "business_owner_tasks" LINE 2: FROM business_owners
>   JOIN services ON business_owner_tasks.s...

I decided to add this:

```
query = query.select_from(BusinessOwnerTask)
```

It complains:

> ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) table name
>   "business_owner_tasks" specified more than once

What is my mistake?

Comment: please paste your model definitions. What is `services`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I change query builder to this one:

```
query = db.session.query(BusinessOwnerTask, BusinessOwner, services) \
            .join(services, BusinessOwnerTask.services_id == services.c.id) \
            .join(BusinessOwner, BusinessOwner.id == BusinessOwnerTask.business_owner_id) \
            .filter(services.c.service_grade_id == search_parameter.service_grade)

        if len(search_parameter.name) > 0:
            query = query.filter(BusinessOwner.name == search_parameter.name)
        if len(search_parameter.service_types) > 0:
            query = query.filter(services.c.service_type_id.in_(search_parameter.service_types))
```

**Tip**:

It is better to first make your query on pure sql on pgAdmin or other tools. Then make your query on ORM tool